# How to declare a controller function that can only access by another controller function and prevent direct access (.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have a controller function called Resend email. That function should only call by the payment function and should prevent direct access, but when a user in that view user should have the capability to reload that view.

How can I create a controller function to fulfill all these requirements? (.NET Core MVC)

Comment: If a method not intended for use outside the controller, can be declared as `private`.

Comment: If you only want to call it from code, it shouldn't be a controller.

Comment: @Samithra niroshana, can you elaborate a little more and show examples?

Comment: Hi @Samithraniroshana, any updates about this case?

Answer (score 1):

> That function should only call by the payment function and should prevent direct access

If you only want to call that method/function from the code of another method(s) instead of exposing it as an action method, you can apply the [`NonAction` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.nonactionattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to the method, like below.

```
public IActionResult ConfirmAccount()
{
    //...
    //code logic here
    //...

    return ResendEmail();
}

[NonAction]
public IActionResult ResendEmail()
{
    //return Ok("success");
    //...
```

Besides, as @CodeCaster mentioned in comment, you can define the function/method in a generic class library etc, rather than in a controller.

Answer (score -1):

If it is necessary to make controller method to access only from another view it is possible to use the following check:

```
public IActionResult CalculateBallance(int id)
{
    // Gets information about the URL of the client's previous request
    // that linked to the current URL.
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Headers["Referer"]))
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    // TODO: ...
}
```

Comment: The referrer is easily spoofed by callers, and not set for API calls.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Might be protected by using [AntiForgeryToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: That doesn't change that fact.

Comment: @CodeCaster: It does, the problem might be solved. But this is not the content of this question.

Comment: No, an anti forgery token doesn't magically prevent malicious users from calling your API. Relying on the referrer and on that token is not a replacement for authorization; they are not security measures, you're advocating harmful practices.

Comment: @CodeCaster: That's right, authorization should be first of all. But that was not the topic of this question.

Comment: No, but now it is the topic of your answer. You say: look at the referrer. I say: don't do that, it's not secure. You say: use the AntiForgeryToken to make it secure, I say: it doesn't do that. Now you say: this question isn't about security. But your answer is, it's an insecure answer.